# This error Comes out of nowhere

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am using SQL in vba and sometimes I encounter an error and never have understood the reason behind it. The program runs fine and suddenly it starts throwing weird things at me.

```
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [test$]", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

There is a sheet called test in my file, but it throws error saying

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004505)':
>       'test$' is not a valid name. Make sure it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long

I have 100 times and there exists such sheet with same name exact, not even a space after or before. What's the issue? please advice. Thanks in advance.

Edit : Changed the Quotes around the query.

Comment: For one, your quotes should be around your SQL query only. But maybe that's just a typo?

Comment: @Bond Thanks for pointing that out, that's just an typo as you said. Is there a simple filtering with aggregation method in VBA without SQL?

Comment: Are you asking a different question or is that related to this one? Excel has the `=SUBTOTAL()` worksheet function that operates only on filtered rows.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one case I have found this to happen.  If the worksheet "test" is created while the current Excel session is active AND the Excel workbook is not writable.  Try to save the workbook, and if it asks you to save it to a different file name, then it is not writable.  I found this error to occur when the Read-Only attribute is set on the workbook file, or the read-only attribute is set on the directory that the workbook is contained it.